# Retrieve values from multi dimensional array using Sphinx PHP API

Tags: php, foreach, sphinx

I'm building search engine with Sphinx, but I'm stuck at the end with displaying results as my PHP knowledge is limited. The request to search server gives me this multi dimensional array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 327919409
            [weight] => 3
            [attrs] => Array
                (
                    [group_id] => 327919409
                    [date] => 2013
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 84811232
            [weight] => 2
            [attrs] => Array
                (
                    [group_id] => 84811232
                    [date] => 2013
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 150252575
            [weight] => 2
            [attrs] => Array
                (
                    [group_id] => 150252575
                    [date] => 2013
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 174947829
            [weight] => 2
            [attrs] => Array
                (
                    [group_id] => 174947829
                    [date] => 2013
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 297809970
            [weight] => 2
            [attrs] => Array
                (
                    [group_id] => 297809970
                    [date] => 2013
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 391669252
            [weight] => 2
            [attrs] => Array
                (
                    [group_id] => 391669252
                    [date] => 2013
                )

        )

)
```

I need to retrieve and list all ID values, I'm trying to use this code but all I get is NULL values from the foreach:

```
$query = $_GET['q'];
$index = "test1";
require_once('sphinxapi.php');
//Sphinx
$s = new SphinxClient;
$s->setServer("localhost", 9312);
$s->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ALL);
$s->SetArrayResult(true);

//Search Query
$result = $s->Query($query, $index);

if ($result['total'] > 0) {

        foreach ($result['matches'] as $key => $id) {
            $ido = $id[$key]->id;
                //Get Column
                $searchColumn = mysql_fetch_array( mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rasti_failai WHERE ID=$ido") );

                //Dump
                var_dump($searchColumn);        
            }


} else {
        echo 'No results found';        
}
```

Any help correcting my foreach loop would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was in my SQL query(?) because I've managed to foreach id's like this:

```
foreach ($result['matches'] as $id) {

    echo $id['id'];
        //$searchColumn = mysql_fetch_array( mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rasti_failai WHERE ID=$ido") );

        //Dump
        //var_dump($searchColumn);       
    }
```

Anyway as this is not problem with foreach, My question is resolved. Thanks anyways who tried to help

Comment: please provide up vote if you think my answer help you access array element properly

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the below line in your `foreach` loop

```
$ido = $id[$key]->id;
```

replace with below

```
$ido = $id["id"];
```

You are looping through array and can access mulch-dimentional array with square brackets, where as you are using syntax for object property.

Comment: Still getting 
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL values